# Use NSString in another class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I simply want to access a NSString from my first class in my second class.

I used properties in my first class and this:

```
NSLog(@"The text is: %@", self.fileText);
```

returns the correct string in my first class.

But in my second class, this:

```
FirstViewController* controller = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"text: %@", controller.fileText);
```

returns (null).

I imported the class correctly.
What could I have done wrong?

Comment: did you add fileText to your .h file and synthesize in your .m file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
//in your first class
NSUserDefaults *strinToSave= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[strinToSave setObject:self.fileText forKey:@"filTextString"];
```

and to retrieve saved data in the second class, use this:

```
NSString *yourString=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"filTextString"];
//use yourString however you want

NSLog(@"%@",yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the second class is either a sub-class of the first class or jus an instance of the class (which seems more likely).

Be sure what you are doing in your init block of the `FirstViewController`, because that's all that's being called for the second implementation and if you have not initialized your string there, the value will be null. So yep, check there.

Comment: OK I understand. The problem is the string is initialized in didSelectRowAtIndexPath because I need the indexPath.row but I can't access it in viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok, so that's the problem. Hmmm Why won't you initialize your new view in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? Otherwise, the string will be empty.One suggestion would be to mark this question as answered and probably create a new one with a new focus on the specific problem.